# How would I go about using the list(element) function? How would you use this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm a python newbie and am using The Python Bible 7 in 1 written by Florian Dedov to learn.
I've been doing well but I've hit a barrier with list functions as described in the book and would like help.
I can't figure out how to use the ***list(element)*** function in the book it is described as ***typecasts element into list***.
My attempt and error have been as follows

numbers= [10,22,61,29]

print(numbers(29))
which gives me type error 'list' object is not callable

How would you use this function properly?

Comment: what is `numbers(29)` supposed to be doing? The book is suggesting that `list({1,2,3})` would turn the set parameter into a list

Comment: That example does not use `list()` at all, so I'm not even sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you are reading a python book which has the phrase: `typecasts element into list.` I would immediately start looking for a different book.

Comment: @quamrana does that phrase mean that its using an outdated version of python?

Comment: @Sayse I'm experimenting with the function trying to figure out different ways to implement it. I just happened to have that list and thought I had to use a preexisting list with this function.  Does that mean that the list(element) function's sole purpose is to turn a set into a list?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm trying to figure out how to use the List(element) function and I used a list I already created because that's how I thought the function operated.

Comment: No, (although it will be very strongly suggested to upgrade to python 3), the use of `typecast` or `casting` seems to come from the `C` programming language and has no relevance in python where you are almost always performing some sort of conversion. So, what is this `list(element)` you indicate comes from the book? I assume you mean `list(iterable)` where some `iterable`, (like a `set`), can be converted to a `list`.

Comment: @quamrana I'm currently using python3.9.1 is this acceptable? I believe what the book means is List(iterable) instead of Lists(element) the book is meant to be easy for someone with no coding experience to read so they may have purposefully not used the word iterable. It could also be a mistake as I have already noticed a few.

Comment: The purpose of `list()` is to produce a list from some other sequence type (tuple, string, set, etc).  But you said you already have a list, so I don't understand why you would need to use `list()` at all.

Comment: @quamrana using the information you've given me I found that Iterables are lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries, strings. this is exactly what the book is covering right now so it must be list(iterable) instead of list(element). How would you use the List(iterable) function? what does it do?

Comment: @quamrana you have answered my question perfectly and clarified everything. I don't need to use the List() function I just did not understand how it worked and what its purpose was. You're amazing thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you so much that helped clarify as well. Although, I would like to ask how you emboldened "List()" when adding a comment here?

Comment: I did it by surrounding the text in backwards single quotes (the same key as `~` on my keyboard.)

Comment: You have said it yourself that an example of an iterable is a string. You could do an experiment using: `c = list("string")` and then `print(c)`

Comment: @quamrana my terminal returned `['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']` thank you again this makes me feel a lot more confident in all the information I just tried to absorb

Comment: So I hope that gives you an insight into how `list(iterable)` gives you a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong function in your example. The Book describes **List(iterable)/ List()** as **List(element)** so that means that the proper use of the "List(element)" function as the book describes it is to convert an iterable (like a set) into a list. The book would call this conversion a typecast.
To summarize the correct use of this function would be to convert an iterable into a list.

A proper example of this would be

```py
C=list("string")

print(C)

This returns ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Answer (score 2):

`print(numbers(29))` needs to be `print(numbers[29])`

The round brackets `(i)` are asking the interpreter to call a function with argument `i`and square brackets `[i]` is looking for index `i` in an object with indexes such as a list.